# Driver doesn't stop on cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I've configured my cluster (1 master / 9 slaves) .
My problem is that when I submit an application (word through `spark-submit` with `deploy-mode cluster`) the driver doesn't stop, even though there is little data.

I submitted the application like that:

```
./spark-submit \
--class wordCount \
--master spark://master:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --supervise \
--executor-cores 1 --total-executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 1g \      
hdfs://master:9000/user/exemple/word3.jar \
hdfs://master:9000/user/exemple/texte.txt
hdfs://master:9000/user/exemple/result 2
```

That's my program:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext import
org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkWordCount {   def main(args: Array[String]) {
  // create Spark context with Spark configuration
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"))

  // get threshold
  val threshold = args(1).toInt

  // read in text file and split each document into words
  val tokenized = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(_.split(" "))

  // count the occurrence of each word
  val wordCounts = tokenized.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

  // filter out words with fewer than threshold occurrences
  val filtered = wordCounts.filter(_._2 >= threshold)

  // count characters
  val charCounts = filtered.flatMap(_._1.toCharArray).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

  System.out.println(charCounts.collect().mkString(", "))   } }
```

Result :
[Application Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efTMB.png)

Comment: It might be hard to answer, if you don't provide a minimal example.

Comment: Excuse me this is actually my first post.
Well, I tried the basic example of wordcount ( link : https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html ), 
and whenever I start the operation, the driver (using the command mentioned in my post) doesn't stop and keeps going on and on despite the fact that my entry is just a small sample of data.

Comment: Oh don't worry :) Just a suggestion. You can use [edit] link to modify your question (we typically expect some form of [mcve]), but just looking at linked code, the missing part is probably `sc.stop()`. Just put it at the end of the main block and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Why are you using master spark? Don't you have YARN?

Comment: When I use yarn, i have this exception "Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
  ", I have this exception ",
Given, I tried to solve it but I did not find a solution

Comment: @ user9613318, It does not work :/ (thanks for your reply)